# Proxy servlet hangs on HttpClient.execute()

Tags: java, proxy, apache-httpclient-4.x

I need to write a servlet that basically just proxies each incoming request to the same URL path on a different host. Here's what I came up with using Apache Commons Http Client 4.1.3:

```
@WebServlet("/data/*")
public class ProxyServlet extends HttpServlet {

  protected void doGet (HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
  throws ServletException, IOException {
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    try {
      String url = getMappedServiceUrlFromRequest(request);
      HttpGet get = new HttpGet(url);
      copyRequestHeaders(request, get);

      HttpResponse getResp = client.execute(get);
      response.setStatus(getResp.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
      copyResponseHeaders(getResp, response);

      HttpEntity entity = getResp.getEntity();
      if (entity != null) {
        OutputStream os = response.getOutputStream();
        try {
          entity.writeTo(os);
        } finally {
          try { os.close(); } catch (Exception ignored) { }
        }
      }
    } catch (Exception e) {
      throw new ServletException(e);
    } finally {
      client.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
    }
  }

  private void getMappedServiceUrlFromRequest (...)
  private void copyResponseHeaders (...)
  private void copyRequestHeaders (...)
}
```

This works just fine the first time the servlet is called. However, after the first time, the servlet hangs on the line *client.execute(get)*.

There are plenty of Google hits for "HttpClient execute hangs", most of which suggest using an instance of ThreadSafeClientConnManager. Tried that, sadly didn't help.

I've spent several hours googling for the problem, but I haven't found anything that fixes it yet. I'd seriously appreciate any pointers as to what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: Did you try enabling debug logging in org.apache.http? That would be my first step.

Comment: similar thread worth reading: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4694419/multiple-post-with-httpclient-4-0-3-hanging-randomly

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you are doing this the hard way. Just write a *Filter* that does the redirect.

Or even just a TCP server that listens at the port and just copies bytes back and forth. You don't really need to engage in the HTTP protocol at all in a proxy, unless you are implementing the CONNECT command, in which case that's the only piece of HTTP you need to understand, and its reply is the only HTTP response you need to know about. Everything else is just bytes.